# Чем отличаются понятия "Обновиться из origin" и "Обновиться из upstream"?

Tags: git, контроль-версий

Обновиться из апстрима — обновить свою локальную версию форка до последней версии основного репозитория, от которого сделан форк.

Обновиться из ориджина — обновить свою локальную версию репозитория до последней удалённой версии этого репозитория.

Я нашел эти определения, но не могу понять в чем их разница. В моём понимании термин "репозиторий" - означает каталог с файлами проекта который находится на сервере GitHub. В чем разница между понятиями "локальная версия форка" и "локальная версия репозитория" если и то и другое является копией "изначального репозитория"?

Чем отличается "последняя версия основного репозитория от которого сделан форк" от "последней удаленной версии этого репозитория"? Основной репозиторий и удаленная версия этого репозитория это не одно и тоже?

Почему Upstream подразумевает изначально созданный проект, а origin подразумевает мою скопированную копию основного проекта находящуюся на github, если само слово origin указывает на изначально созданный проект, по логике, но на его месте стоит слово upstream? это сбивает с толку.

Comment: Ну вот ты фыркнул проект и делаешь что-то в команде разрабов с этим. И они обновляются из ориджина, из вашей собственной репы, а тот проект, от которого ты форкнул никак на это не влияет. Основной проект развивается самостоятельно, А твой форк - отдельно от него....А потом в основном проекте что-то супер дупер фичи завезли и ты понял, а в вашей отдельной разработке тоже они не помешали бы - делаешь обновление уже с апстрима. Они полностью не зависимы друг от друга

Comment: Слово `origin` указывает на то откуда взялась копия кода на диске. А она, скорее всего, взялась из форка, а не из исходного репозитория. И пушить свои изменения вы будете в этот `origin`, а не в исходный репозиторий (в который у вас и доступа-то нет скорее всего).  Т.е. тут `origin` это не «оригинал» (как противопоставление копии), а «место происхождения» (вашей копии).

Answer (score 5):

Для начала "репозиторий" понимается неправильно. git - это система с распределенным репозиториями. После выполнения fork на github и clone на своей машите будет целых три независимых репозитория. `origin` - обычно используется в репозитории на машине пользователя в качестве алиаса для того удаленного репозитория, из которого был клонирован этот и куда будут отправляться изменения. `upstream` - обычно используется в репозитории на машине пользователя в качестве алиаса для того удаленного репозитория, из которого был форкнут тот репозиторий, из которого клонировали этот. На практике удаленных репозиториев может быть куда больше двух, соответственно можно делать и неограниченное количество произвольных алиасов для них.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]