# Мастер, удалённый, локальный репозитории, репозиторий и форк, в чём отличия?

Tags: git, терминология, репозиторий, git-репозиторий

Термины (T) и то как я их понимаю (Me):

(T)

Репозиторий Git — каталог файловой системы, в котором находятся: файлы конфигурации, файлы журналов операций, выполняемых над репозиторием, индекс расположения файлов и хранилище, содержащее сами контролируемые файлы.

(Me)

Репозиторий - папка, в которой находятся файлы проекта, index.html и т.д., но в отличие от просто папки на пк, эта папка находится на удалённом сервере (Гитхаб) и только поэтому мы не можем назвать ее просто папкой, а придумали для этого новое слово, которого конечно очень не хватало нашей памяти :)

(T)

Локальный репозиторий — репозиторий, расположенный на локальном компьютере разработчика в каталоге. Именно в нём происходит разработка и фиксация изменений, которые отправляются в удалённый репозиторий.

(Me)

локальный репозиторий - репозиторий на пк, где происходит разработка и фиксируются изменения, которые отправляются на удалённый репозиторий, то есть по сути это и есть та же самая папка с файлами проекта на нашем пк, которую никаким репозиторием и называть то не надо было, но мы назвали, ок.

(T)

Мастер (Master) — главная или основная ветка репозитория.
мастер-репозиторий, главный репозиторий, от него начинаются форки.

(Me)

Мастер-репозиторий - папка с файлами проекта находящаяся на удалённом сервере (Гитхаб) к которой есть доступ у лица обладающего правами администратора на эту папку, и через которое (лицо), идёт всё взаимодействите с файлами данной папки (пулреквесты, и т.д.), называющаяся словом "мастер" только потому что с файлами из нее нельзя взаимодействовать напрямую,
(с целью сохранения достигнутого в проекте прогресса)
но можно по согласованию с лицом, которое имеет над этой папкой - власть.
(но если открыт публичный доступ то можно сделать форк).

(T)

Форк-репозиторий - копия мастер-репозитория находящаяся на сервере Гитхаб.

(Me)

Форк-репозиторий - скопированная в свой профиль на гитхабе версия мастер-репозитория, с которой можно спокойно работать, не боясь нанести ущерба тому, что уже сделано.

(T)

Удалённый репозиторий — репозиторий, находящийся на удалённом сервере. Это общий репозиторий, в который приходят все изменения и из которого забираются все обновления.

(Me)

удалённый репозиторий - подождите, и как описанный выше термин отличить от мастер-репозитория?
или как "удалённый репозиторий" отличить от простого термина "репозиторий"
(ведь мы придумали новое слово "репозиторий" как раз потому, чтобы подчеркнуть удалённость нашей папки и нахождение её на удаленном сервере, а не нахождение её на пк).
получается если расшифровать "удалённый репозиторий" получится "удалённая, удалённая от пк папка"?
То есть какая-то супер удалённая папка?
Помогите разобраться...

Comment: 1) git-репозиторий может находиться где угодно не привязан ни к каким серверам — именно это отличает децентрализованный git от централизованных аналогов вроде svn; 2) Не любая папка с файлами может считаться git-репозиторием; 3) Слово "мастер" это всего лишь соглашение между людьми и оно не имеет никакого технического смысла (и кстати от этого слова в последнее время массово отказываются)

Comment: 4) Слово "форк" это тоже всего лишь соглашение, которое в общем случае тоже не имеет никакого отношения к гитхабу, а с точки зрения гитхаба он не любую копию считает форком; 5) В принципе никто не запрещает разместить "удалённый" репозиторий на том же самом компьютере, просто в другой папке (и делать pull/push в эту папку), так что я не вижу смысла рассуждать о масштабах "удалённости"

Comment: возможно будет полезно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1365341/%d0%a7%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-origin-%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7-upstream/1365719#1365719

Comment: Что это за поток сознания и в чём собственно вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Репозиторий - это общее название папки, в которой хранится проект (он вовсе не обязательно должен находиться на удалённом сервере). Придумано это слово для удобства, чтобы не говорить "папка с проектом". Тем более, что в репозитории хранятся далеко не все файлы, нужные для его запуска, так что приведённое словосочетание ещё и неточно отражает суть понятия.

И уже репозиторий может быть удалённым или локальным (по месту хранения), мастер- или форк- (по праву разработки).

[image: Схема]

Comment: [git remote add origin ~/repos/myproject.git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34507038) — это локальный или удалённый репозиторий?)

Comment: Схема неполная. Я привёл только интересующие вопрошающего термины.